# How to wait for ENTER key press in Python (2.7 + )?

Tags: python

I would like to know a simple way to wait for a user to press a specific key, like Enter or Escape (but not both), and then execute the code further after sensing the key press.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
raw_input('Press enter to continue: ')
```

Or, in Python 3:

```
input('Press enter to continue: ')
```

Comment: k.. but if i really wana check whether the pressed key is "Enter" or not... what should i do?

Comment: `not input('Press enter to continue: ')` evaluates to `True` if only enter was pressed.

Comment: If so then how can we read enter key press for some amount of times(say "Press enter 5 times"), and then continue to excute the code??

Comment: Put it in a `for` loop: `for _ in range(5): raw_input('Press enter:')`

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
raw_input('Press Enter')
```

That will print the message and then wait for you to press enter.

Comment: k.. but if i really wana check whether the pressed key is "Enter" or not... what should i do?