# Ending a python program with user input

Tags: python

I am trying to use user input to end a program. I want them to just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when they need to exit. What am I doing wrong?

```
# 1)Pace.py
# Converts miles per hour to minutes per mile.

print ("Hello! This program will convert the miles per hour you got on your treadmill to >minutes per mile.") # Greeting

def main() :    # Defines the function main

    while True :    # The loop can repeat infinitely for multiple calculations.
        mph = eval (input ("Please enter your speed in miles per hour. ") )    # Asks for >user input and assigns it to mph.
        mpm = 1 / (mph / 60)    # The user input is divided by 60, and that is divided by 1. >This is assigned to mpm.
        print ("Your speed was", mpm, "minutes per mile!")    # Prints out the miles per >minute.
        if mph == input ("") :    # If the user entered nothing...
            break    # ...The program stops
main()    # Runs main.
```

Comment: Please fix your coding - this cannot have been your original program. In any case, you probably wanted `if mph==""` for no input. I strongly advise against using "eval" in this way, it's very risky.

Comment: why are you using eval?

Comment: You shouldn't use `eval` on the input. cast as an `int`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read ENTER key press in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374944/how-to-read-enter-key-press-in-python)

Comment: More descripton needed... at which points do you want ENTER to exit? For instance, user sees "Please enter your..." and just hits ENTER. Des that mean its time to exit?

Comment: You could use a tkinter loop and bind an exit funtion to the enter key

Comment: @tdelaney, I think the OP means an empty string as the `if mph == input ("")` suggests

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - likely, but the example code is written as though the idea is to wait for ENTER after the program does its calculation. It can be hard to guess intent with sample programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if not mph` will catch an empty string as input and end your loop.

Don't use `eval` cast as `int` after you have checked for an empty string as input.

```
 def main() :    # Defines the function main
    while True :    # The loop can repeat infinitely for multiple calculations.
        mph = (input ("Please enter your speed in miles per hour or hit enter to exit. ") )    # Asks for >user input and assigns it to mph.
        if not mph:    # If the user entered nothing...
            break    # ...The program stops
        mpm = 1 / (int(mph) / 60)    # The user input is divided by 60, and that is divided by 1. >This is assigned to mpm.
        print ("Your speed was", mpm, "minutes per mile!")    # Prints out the miles per >minute.
main()    # Runs main.
```

You should use a `try/except` to catch incorrect input to avoid a `ValueError` and check that mph is > 0 to avoid a `ZeroDivisionError`:

```
def main() :    # Defines the function main
    while True :    # The loop can repeat infinitely for multiple calculations.
        mph = (raw_input ("Please enter your speed in miles per hour. ") )    # Asks for >user input and assigns it to mph.
        if not mph:    # If the user entered nothing...
            break    # ...The program stops
        try:
            mpm = 1 / (int(mph) / 60.)    # The user input is divided by 60, and that is divided by 1. >This is assigned to mpm.
        except (ZeroDivisionError,ValueError):
            print("Input must be an integer and > 0")
            continue
        print ("Your speed was", mpm,
        "minutes per mile!")    # Prints out the miles per >minute.
main()    # Runs main.
```

Comment: Thanks for the first one, but what does the second do? And why does it have to be int?